# Java swing won't display g.drawImage() until repaint() is called

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint, drawimage

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);

    g2.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 200);
    g2.drawImage(map, 0, 0, 1004, 687, null);
}
```

This is the code for the paintComponent in my JPanel.

When the application is launched, I can see the rectangle (which is only there because I wanted to check if paintComponent was being called). But **the map doesn't draw until I force a repaint** by resizing the window or pressing a button that forces repaint().

I tried calling validate() in several places because some answers suggested that, but it didn't work.

Comment: How do you obtain `map`? Are you using `ImageIO.read(...)`? Note that `validate()` shouldn't do anything of use here since it is not associated with repainting the component but rather with laying out its child components (if any).

Comment: I have the map as a private field that is instantiated when the JPanel object is created. So, I have private Image map = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/hw8/data/campus_map.jpg");

Comment: What happens if you use `ImageIO.read(new File(...))`?

Comment: Don't, ever, use any path with "src" in, the path will not exist when the project is exported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g2.drawImage(map, 0, 0, 1004, 687, null);
```

Try using:

```
g2.drawImage(map, 0, 0, 1004, 687, this);
```

Maybe the image isn't completely read at the time the paintComponent() method is invoked. The "this" will cause the image to be painted when the I/O is finished. That is the panel will be notified that I/O is done and the panel will repaint itself.